# Trello power-up get the Board's ID on Initialize

Tags: javascript, trello, trello-powerup

Is there a way to get the current ID of the board currently using the power-up?

something like this in my `client.js`

```
var Promise = TrelloPowerUp.Promise;

TrelloPowerUp.initialize({
    // Start adding handlers for your capabilities here!
  'current-board': function(t, options){
    console.log(boardId) // I want to get the board's Id
  },

    'card-buttons': function(t, options) {
    return t.set("member", "shared", "hello", "world")
    .then(function(){
        return [{
        icon: BLACK_ROCKET_ICON,
              text: 'Estimate Size',
              callback: function(t) {
                return t.popup({
                  title: "Estimation",
                  url: 'estimate.html',
                });
              }
            }];
    })
    },
});
```

when the powerup is Initialize I want to console log the `board Id`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used inside your client.js file to fetch the board id or name and so on.

```
TrelloPowerUp.initialize({
    'current-board': function(t, options){
    t.board('id')
        .then(function (name) {
            console.log(name);
    });
});
```

The above code works for `t.board('name')` as well as for cards like `t.card('name')`.

Comment: it did not work for me, is there any capabilities to enable for this to work?